# How C++11 threads are wrapped around pthreads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, pthreads, posix

So C++11 threads are wrappers around pthreads on most systems, I am confused how the syntax for going from a variadic function to a more strict function with a specified return type might work (i.e. the callback function with pthreads) can someone give an example that could illustrate the same?

Comment: Could you refine your question?  I'm not entirely sure what you are asking.  Perhaps you can give a code example with `std::thread` and/or with pthreads to demonstrate what you are confused on.

Comment: "C++11 threads are wrappers around pthreads" not necessarily.

Comment: Specifically what 'variadic' function?

Comment: Wrapper around C++ 11?  I'm not sure how the two are connected.  But when I use pthread_attr_getstacksize()  in a C++11 thread, it reports no errors.  (I'm not sure if I confirmed the value it reported.)

Comment: "So C++11 threads are wrappers around pthreads," Maybe, maybe not. They're certainly not required to be. Some systems don't have pthreads.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have a C style interface that looks like:

```
Foo run( Foo(*)(void*), void* );
```

And you want to write:

```
template<class F, class...Args>
std::result_of<F(Args...)>
smart_run( F&& f, Args&&... args );
```

This is analogous to what you need to do to implement `std::thread` on top of pthreads.  I simplified stuff a bit, because it is noise (no std ref support, no decaying, etc).

For the first step, take `F` and `Args...` and bind them up.  Something like `std::bind(f, args...)`  that returns a zero-arg function that returns the result.

With that, we just need to solve:

```
template<class F>
std::result_of<F()>
smart_run( F&& f );
```

which takes an arbitrary callable, then uses `run` above to run it.

The trick is to create a copy of `f` on the free store and a function that calls it like this:

```
template<class F>
std::result_of<F()>
smart_run( F&& f ){
  struct data{
    F f;
    std::result_of_t<F()> r;
  };
  data*p = new data{std::forward<F>(f)};
  Foo ignored=run(
    [](void* p){
      data* self=static_cast<data*>(p);
      auto& f=self->f;
      self->r = f();
      return Foo{}; // whatever
    },
    p
  );
  auto r=data->r;
  delete data;
  return r;
}
```

Now, the r is assigned instead of constructed.  But the core of the idea -- that you pass the fancy callable in the `void*`, andmthe function unwraps it and interacts with it, and done is there.

In a real thread on pthread, you'd pass a pointer-to-std::thread-state to the pthread invoker.  It would set whatever up, invoke the stored procedure, and when done would take the return value and store it in the internal std::thread state (if needed).  Then you could get that data by interacting with the internal std::thread state.

Or something else roughly equivalent.

Comment: I dont understand one thing here, why do you need the struct data? Why can't we simply cast the function to void*, pass the function to a custom lambda and in that lambda cast that function back to its original type and call it?

Comment: @curious I am not restricting myself to function pointers.  There could be lifetime issues with the data: in a real thread/async environment, the run code and shutdown code are separate.  It is just a sketch if the technique.  Note that above, I have to carry the return value out of the run call somewhere: I do it in the data struct.  For `std::thread` that extra channel may not be needed, but the lifetime of the callable needs to be managed.